# How can I run command inside virtualenv in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, pipenv

I develop my own django-based project with pipenv.
Couple days ago I created simple bash script to speed up boring stuff.

All time I run terminal, go to the same directory and execute `pipenv shell`, after that I open up project in VScode `code .` and started `python manage.py runserver` for looking up my progress.

I try create script which do the same stuff but simplied, just run `webber` and here go (it comes from /usr/local/bin).

But I have one problem of these, I can't keep my  `pipenv shell` running and execute `python manage.py runserver` at the same time. I mean when I stop Ctrl+C python server I don't receive my virtual enviroment (this happed in bash script ~ normally work fine).

However, server is start up, so it's virtual env.
I tried with `pipenv run` command but it doesn't get inside virtual env at all.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Documents/myprojects/Webber
code .
source $(pipenv --venv)/bin/activate
python manage.py runserver
```

**My question is:** How can I run command inside virtualenv in shell script and receive this subshell?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the full path to the virtualenv folder instead of `pipenv` command. For example, if you created the virtual environment in you home directory called `venv-webber`:

`source $HOME/venv-webber/bin/activate`

Comment: I tried it but Ctrl + C terminate bash script, no only python dev server (and I don't have any idea how to do this). I don't receive active virtual env in terminal.

Comment: I think the problem you are facing has to do with the fact that you are terminating your shell session (by running Ctrl + C) which causes your script to stop and this case, the question is wrongly framed. 
If you want your script to carry on running after you terminate your shell session, you can either run it using `nohup` or `tmux`.
If you want the script to run in the background just run it with a `&` at the end (again, note that if you close the shell, the script will stop):